# CSS animation will not run at original JS state

Tags: javascript, css

These states do pretty much everything I need them to. The only problem is that the animation does not run under `.select-sentence.selected` when the state is initialized.

For some reason, it runs only when the element has been selected, then is hovered over, and finally the mouse goes out of the target area.

I'd like it to run when the state is initialized, not on hover+mouseout

```
/*selecting animation*/ 
.select-sentence.selected {
  transition: box-shadow .175s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,.91,1,2.21);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -19px 0 #86D7F7;
}

/* unselected hover */
.select-sentence:not(.selected):hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 #86D7F7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* deselecting animation */
.select-sentence:hover:not(.hover){
  transition: box-shadow .175s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.25,.1,.25,1);
}

/* selected hover */
.select-sentence.hover{
    box-shadow: inset 0 -22px 0 #D0F2FE;
}
```

Link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/vvesper/pen/abbqQGm

Comment: So when the page loads you want all the sentences to be highlighted?

Comment: Can you describe what "it" means? In FF, hover, click, hover has animations working just fine.

Comment: The animation for "select-sentence.selected" doesn't run when it's selected, it only runs when the sentence has already been selected then the mouse hovers over it and mouses out.

Comment: So when clicked, it highlights but you need the light blue (#D0F2FE) as the background instead of #86D7F7?

Comment: No, that's not it. The colors and states themselves are all correct. The Bezier curve under "selected-sentence.selected" does not occur when the sentence goes from unselected-hover to selected, like it is supposed to.  This curve transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,.91,1,2.21); is only visible when the sentence goes from selected-hover to selected.

Answer (score 0):

please what are you trying to achieve with this rule

```
  .select-sentence:hover:not(.hover){
    transition: box-shadow .175s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.25,.1,.25,1);
  }
```

from your code, I noticed you are adding a `.hover` class to elements when you hover over them. But it looks like you are  checking if an element which you hovered on doesn't have a `.hover` class.

let me understand what you mean by `/* deselecting animation */` it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The bezier timing function under `.select-sentence.selected` is not used because the `.select-sentence:hover:not(.hover)` rule has higher specificity and takes precedence.

Usage of the `:hover` pseudo class to set a `.hover` class that mirrors the pseudo class may be causing confusion, particularly if the effect could be achieved without doing so.

This snippet demonstrates the transition on-click duration being take from the second CSS rule. Colors have been changed to accentuate which rule is being used. Notice that on mouseout, the duration is taken from the first rule because hover is no longer in effect.

```js
"use strict";
$(".select-sentence").hover(function(e){
  $(e.target).addClass('hover');
  $(e.target).removeClass('unselected');
  }, function(e){
  $(e.target).removeClass('hover');
});


$(".select-sentence").click(function(e){
  $(e.target).removeClass('hover');
  const alreadySelected = $(e.target).hasClass('selected');
  const selectedHover = $(e.target).hasClass('selected', 'hover');
  $(".select-sentence").removeClass('selected');
  if (!alreadySelected) {
    $(e.target).addClass('selected');
  }
  if (selectedHover) {
    $(e.target).addClass('unselected');
  }
});

// $(".select-sentence").click(function(e){
//   $(e.target).removeClass('hover', 'selected');
//   const alreadySelectHover = $(e.target).hasClass('selected', 'hover');
//   $('.select-sentence').removeClass('selected');
//   if alreadySelectHover {
//     $(e.target).addClass('unselect');
//   }
// });
```

```css
p {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.directions {
  color: #719b07;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.paragraph {
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: justify;
 /*  margin-right: 550px; */
  line-height: 1.9em;
}

/* selected hover */
.select-sentence.hover.selected {
  transition: box-shadow .175s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.05, .86, .77);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -23px 0 yellow;
  user-select: none;
}

/*selecting animation from hover and not hover*/ 
.select-sentence.selected {
  transition: box-shadow .175s;
  transition-duration: 1s; /* for demonstration */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1,.91,1,2.21);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -22px 0 cyan;
}

/* unselected hover */
.select-sentence:not(.selected):hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 silver;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* deselecting animation */
.select-sentence:hover:not(.hover){
  transition: box-shadow .175s;
  transition-duration: 5s;  /* for demonstration */
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.25,.1,.25,1);
}

/* selected hover */
.select-sentence.hover{
    box-shadow: inset 0 -22px 0 green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- body-html -->
<p class= "directions">Select the sentence with a sensory detail that describes a <b>sight</b>.</p>

<p class = "paragraph"><br>
  <span class="select-sentence">The king and queen announced they would have a feast at the palace.</span></div>
  <span class="select-sentence">The harvest had happened in August, the time when the summer's riot had ceased to flower.</span> 
  <span class="select-sentence">The ground's vegetation curled into itself, fading brownness.</span> 
  <span class="select-sentence"> Ripe fruits fallen from trees burst open, leaving beads of red and purple amoung the leaves.</span>
  <span class= "select-sentence"> All the people in the land had been invited, from courtiers to peasants.</span>
  <span class= "select-sentence"> Everyone, that is, except the Goblin King.</span></p>
```